# Python get href under div tag

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, screen-scraping

I am creating a tool using Python that downloads all photos and videos posted by a user on Instagram. All I wanted to do now is to extract the link of all posts so that I can run them in a loop and download all posts.

[image]

This is the href that I wanna extract. I tried out all solutions on stack overflow, but nothing worked out. That is the reason why I am asking this question. Here is my code for ur reference:

```
import urllib.request as reqq
from selenium import webdriver

url = input("Enter the link:")

browser = webdriver.Chrome("D:\\Python_Files\\Programs\\chromedriver.exe")

browser.get(url)

#URLs of all posts are extracted. This is whr I need help

for x in range(len(extracted_urls)):
    img_url = ""
    vid_url = ""
    
    try:
        
        vid_url = browser.find_element_by_class_name('_5wCQW').find_element_by_tag_name('video').get_attribute('src')
        reqq.urlretrieve(vid_url,f"D:\\instavid{x}.mp4")    
        
    except: 
        
        img_url = browser.find_element_by_class_name('KL4Bh').find_element_by_tag_name('img').get_attribute('src')
        reqq.urlretrieve(img_url,f"D:\\instaimg{x}.jpg")
    
browser.close()
```

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: @AndrejKesely URL of?

Comment: URL of the page you want to scrap.

Comment: Here u go: https://www.instagram.com/cristiano/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the class name to identify the elements, but that's programmatically generated and it won't work. In order to scrape it you can use css selector like the below one

```
 list = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('article > div a')
 for element in list:
    print(element.get_attribute('href')) #this will give you all the urls
```

Comment: Thx man! That really helped! Would u mind explaining how ```list = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('article > div a')``` works? And I am only able to get the 12 most recent posts of the user. Is there any way to get all posts?

Comment: that's a css selector first gets the article element, ">" means the direct child of "article" and "div a" - it's the containing element of the div ( tells the browser like this - "give me the div which has an "a" element).  In order to get more elements - you need to scroll in the page. The first 12 - are those who are loaded

Comment: here is how you can scroll automatically - https://dev.to/mr_h/python-selenium-infinite-scrolling-3o12

Comment: Okay Alin. If u feel that my question is good and has been well-framed, then pls consider upvoting my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Beautifulsoup. You can easily parse html and xml.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '<div><div><a href="/p/CFShhjj"></a></div></div>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
for tag in soup.find_all():
if tag.name=='a':
    print(tag['href'])


OUT : /p/CFShhjj
```

Comment: Thx! Can u pls explain how u got the value for ```data```?

Comment: I took a dummy data.. you can pass your html data

Answer (score 1):

The data you see on the page is generated programmatically and stored inside JSON within the page. Use this example to extract the media data:

```
import re
import json
import requests


url = 'https://www.instagram.com/cristiano/'
html_doc = requests.get(url).text
data = json.loads(re.search(r'window\._sharedData = ({.*?});', html_doc).group(1))

def find_media(data):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        for k, v in data.items():
            if k == '__typename' and v in ('GraphImage', 'GraphVideo'): 
                yield data
            else:
                yield from find_media(v)
    elif isinstance(data, list):
        for v in data:
            yield from find_media(v)

for media in find_media(data):
    print('http://instagram.com/p/{}/'.format(media['shortcode']))
    if media['__typename'] == 'GraphImage':
        print(media['display_url']) 
    else:
        print(media['video_url'])
```

Prints:

```
...

http://instagram.com/p/CE2D7zcAFrq/
https://instagram.fbts6-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s1080x1080/118883515_338753734147784_3257042213665207515_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbts6-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=108&_nc_ohc=Duxo0dZ3q8oAX8ps1u6&_nc_tp=15&oh=e52995d9569e7dde5c348a5eb1c4a886&oe=5F8F1B14
http://instagram.com/p/CE2D7zbAMrJ/
https://instagram.fbts6-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s1080x1080/119056544_318190815934349_3868576271600213484_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbts6-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=105&_nc_ohc=Sfy0ykNdpxsAX9kOZqy&_nc_tp=15&oh=b48009b98e0a4b6483f79902d3253d12&oe=5F8F11FB
http://instagram.com/p/CEy7I6yAm9i/
https://instagram.fbts6-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s1080x1080/118877779_2707314466207997_7737960511758007253_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbts6-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=1&_nc_ohc=prF2yBSpK34AX8TSiuX&_nc_tp=15&oh=bdfc5b9d1914bdd3470209a64a5e155b&oe=5F8DEBFF
http://instagram.com/p/CEy7I6yg2Op/
https://instagram.fbts6-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s1080x1080/118784068_748127092633181_2341530667249985288_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbts6-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=105&_nc_ohc=_ynvOYOBxY4AX_B22yF&_nc_tp=15&oh=e5e9d716421cd3ea0edb71adeebe8ebe&oe=5F8F3798
http://instagram.com/p/CEy7I6zA6nU/
https://instagram.fbts6-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s1080x1080/118555638_778542006213962_8711737455993781057_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbts6-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=102&_nc_ohc=MVPAjHvN3QkAX9uawMn&_nc_tp=15&oh=cefd5a6162af11327ab9d1d4bf94df7a&oe=5F8FCF5B
http://instagram.com/p/CEy7I63Aq9f/
https://instagram.fbts6-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s1080x1080/118782135_760435874772485_2807641115290436245_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbts6-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=105&_nc_ohc=SUZnVsn1EU4AX8MUj30&_nc_tp=15&oh=7937a7c235a54b271a869596c837fae6&oe=5F907287
http://instagram.com/p/CEy7I64AvaZ/
https://instagram.fbts6-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s1080x1080/118651624_163760538669975_655651222517528584_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbts6-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=103&_nc_ohc=8mj5Ysn75pMAX9dpSDA&_nc_tp=15&oh=6c33025592ee8f4569ad5d016e69785b&oe=5F8FF67B
```

Comment: Hey! Thx man! But since it is too long, I am going with Alin Stelian's answer. But I really appreciate ur effort. Thx!

Comment: If u feel that my question is good and has been framed well, then pls consider upvoting my question. Thank you!